# SugarCRM - call js functions from views (editviewdefs.php for example)

Tags: javascript, view, sugarcrm

in SugarCRM, i want to edit the lead edit view, so i can call a js function when the user leaves the focus on one of the text boxes (onblur).
i edited the editviewdefs.php file - added a 'customcode' to 'phone_work', with  tag:

```
array (
  array('name'=>'last_name',
        'displayParams'=>array('required'=>true),
  ),
  array(
  'name' => 'phone_work',
  'customCode' => '<input name="phone_work"  id="phone_work" size="30" maxlength="25" type="text" value="{$fields.phone_work.value}" onblur="hello()">'
  ),
),
```

as you can see , i call the js function hello().
i added the js function to jssource\src_files\modules\leads\lead.js and Rebuild JS Compressed Files using the admin.
the function is this:

function hello()
{
    alert('asaf');
}

it doesn't work and the function is not called, why ? 
is that the right way to use js functions in views ?

Answer (score 1):

You would need to add it to a js file named custom/modules/Leads/Lead.js. Then, copy your customized editviewdefs.php file to the custom/modules/Leads/metadata/ directory ( create it if it's not done yet ), and add this to the end of it...

```
$viewdefs['Leads']['EditView']['templateMeta']['includes'][] = 'custom/modules/Leads/Lead.js';
```

However watch out since this stuff is version specific, took me hours to figure out my version (SugarCRM CE 5.5) was more like `Leads,  EditView , templateMeta, includes, file, 'path'`